# OpenCL minification and obfuscation

Tags: opencl, obfuscation, minify, webcl

As OpenCL-enabled software needs to be packaged with source code of OpenCL kernels, minification and obfuscation seems to be a standard requirement for OpenCL deployment, at least for commercial applications.

Which tools could be used for minification/obfuscation of OpenCL/WebCL code?

Update: my deployment target is WebCL, so I am mostly interested in minification, but obfuscation could provide similar result.

Comment: Have you considered generating your kernels into SPIR?
SPIR is a standard for non-source kernel representation https://www.khronos.org/spir. OpenCL platforms are now rolling out SPIR support http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2013-12-27/opencl-spir-by-example/

Comment: My target is WebCL, which is written against OpenCL 1.1 spec, thus no SPIR.

Answer (score 3):

Pack kernel code inside C string or compile it & save to binary or SPIR (as **Ruyk** said). Even if binary is disassembled, complicated kernels are usually not that easy to understand. E. g. in game development, shaders are stored in source code.

Comment: My deployment target is WebCL, and my main concern is about sending redundant source bytes over network. So I mostly need OpenCL minifier, albeit an obfuscator could work as well.